# The Form is not working using React Js and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, material-ui

I am new to react JS and material UI.
If i am typing something in the text field, its capturing the value(debug and checked) but not displaying in the form.

Please have a look at the code. I am getting the form values and errors also perfectly but cant see the values on the page.

Some thing stopping to see what i am typing on the text fields.

```
class Header extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state={
            projectName: '',
            projectNameError :'',
            description: '',
            descriptionError:'',
            module: '',
            moduleError:'',
            AssetValue:'',
            AssetValueError:''
        }
    }

    change (event){
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

 validate = () => {
    let isError = false;
    const errors = {
        AssetValueError :'',
        descriptionError :'',
        projectNameError : '',
        descriptionError :'',
        moduleError : ''

    };

    if(this.state.projectName.length < 5){
        isError = 'true';
        errors.projectNameError = "projectName is mandatory";
    }

    if(this.state.description.length < 5){
        isError = 'true';
        errors.descriptionError = "description is mandatory";
    }

    if(isError){
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            ...errors
        });
    }

    return isError; 
  } 

    onSubmit (evnt){
        evnt.preventDefault();
        const error = this.validate();
        console.log("the values are",this.state);
        if(!error){
                this.setState({
                    projectName: '',
                    projectNameError :'',
                    description: '',
                    descriptionError:'',
                    module: '',
                    moduleError:'',
                    AssetValue:'',
                    AssetValueError:'',
                })
            }
    };

    render(){

        return (
              <div className = "container">
              <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Project Name:</label>
                      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                      <TextField 
                            name="projectName" hintText="projectName" floatingLabelText="projectName"
                            errorText={this.state.projectNameError}
                            value ={this.state.projectName}
                            onChange={event => this.change(event)} floatingLabelFixed />
                        </MuiThemeProvider>
                    </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Description:</label>
                  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                  <TextField
                            name="description" hintText="description" floatingLabelText="description"
                            errorText={this.state.descriptionError}
                            value ={this.state.description} 
                            onChange={event => this.change(event)} floatingLabelFixed />
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Module:</label>
                  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                  <TextField 
                        name="module" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Module" 
                        errorText={this.state.moduleError} 
                        value ={this.state.module}
                        onChange={event => this.change(event)}/>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                <label>Choose Asset Name:</label>
                    <select name="AssetValue" onChange={event => this.change(event)}>
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="BMI">BMI</option>
                        <option value="GYPSY">GYPSY</option>
                        <option value="PRS">PRS</option>
                     </select>
                </div>

                <button onClick={(evnt) => this.onSubmit(evnt)}>Submit</button>


                <div>
                    <button onClick={(event) => this._onButtonClick(event)}>Button</button>
                        {this.state.showComponent ?<NewComponent /> : null}
                </div>
              </form>
             </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

I spotted little mistake from your code.

You are updating your state based on your target's name.

```
  change (event){
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

But your "real" input field which is not "TextField" doesn't have name as prop.

Actually TextField is just a style wrapper for actual input field.

You can check this out by opening chrome react dev tools.

So in order to update your value based on name, you should pass "inputProps" to your TextField component.

I recommend you to read this document first.

[TextField API](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/)